# Java code for downloading files

Tags: java, download

(original title: help a newbie (Java))

I need a java code for downloading files from the internet ..For example I want to download doc,pdf files from the internet means i have to do it through my code ..So can anyone help me

Comment: Some advice for a newbie - you won't get far just asking for teh codez on this forum. Start with what you have done so far to help yourself and where you have got stuck, and we will help with those problems. But nobody is here to do all of your work for you for free.

Comment: Retitle your question with what you're actually trying to accomplish (rather than just "Help a newbie"), and you'll likely have better luck.

Comment: I've edited the title so that shouldn't be a problem any more.

Answer (score 5):

It's easiest if you use Apache [Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/io/):

```
IOUtils.copy(
    new URL("http://www.server.com/file.doc").openStream(), 
    new FileOutputStream("C:/path/to/file.doc")
);
```

Otherwise, you have to write a loop and use a byte array as buffer, which can be a bit tricky to get exactly right.

Answer (score 4):

```
URL url = new URL("http://farm6.static.flickr.com/5035/5802797131_a729dac808_b.jpg");
ReadableByteChannel readableByteChannel = Channels.newChannel(url.openStream());
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("image.jpeg");
fos.getChannel().transferFrom(readableByteChannel, 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);
```

Use Java Non-blocking I/O

Answer (score 1):

Strange that you would ask this in 2010 http://www.daniweb.com/forums/thread84370.html

Comment: Must be a troll copying crap from the web.

Comment: Or someone who doesn't know how to formulate a smart question in English and unfortunately copied the wrongly formulated one from the internets which he found during searching for the answer. By the way, if this was been posted as a **comment** on the question, I'd upvoted it, but not this. Please don't post comments as answers.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Apache HTTPClient project: http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/

There are tons of samples on the Samples section of the site: http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/httpcomponents/oac.hc3x/trunk/src/examples/

And the User Guide is also quite good!

Comment: Apache HTTPClient is an excellent, powerful library. But I think it would be intimidating for a newbie to use. I think Balus had a good idea in suggesting the simpler API complete with a gentle tutorial.